# Calculate the MSE(T)

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose that each measurement $X_i$ can be seen as $X_i = μ + U_i$, where the $U_i$ are i.i.d. $N(0, σ^2)$ random variables. 
>   Consider the estimator $T=\frac{1}{20}\sum_{i=1}^{20}U_i^2$ for $σ^2$. 
>   Calculate the MSE(T). 
>   Hint: use that $E[U_i^4]=3σ^4$.

Solve:

$MSE(T)=Var(T)+(E[T]-\sigma^2)^2$

$E[T]=\frac{1}{20}\cdot 20 \cdot E[U_i^2]=E[U_i^2]=\sigma^2$

$Var(T)=\frac{1}{20^2} \cdot 20 \cdot Var(U_i^2)= \frac{Var(U_i^2)}{20}$

$Var(U_i^2)=E[U_i^4]-(E[U_i^2])^2=3σ^4-\sigma^4=2σ^4$

So $Var(T)=\frac{σ^4}{10}$ and $MSE(T)=\frac{σ^4}{10}+(\sigma^2-\sigma^2)^2=\frac{σ^4}{10}$

Is this the correct way to solve it? My only doubt is  when I compute $E[T]$, I don't know if I have to assume it equal to zero since the distribution is $N=(0,\sigma^2)$ or maybe just assume that $T$ is un unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$ (what I did)?

Comment: [Same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089410/calculate-the-mset?noredirect=1) was asked sometime back (now deleted) and surprisingly with the same formatting as far as I remember.

Comment: Yes, it was a friend of mine (we are doing the same course and we are struggling with the same question) and since it was posted in a wrong moment (just a few views and no answer) we decided to repost it with my account and see if someone can help us! :)

Comment: We don't draw attention to our questions by deleting previous copies and posting the same thing again (within a few hours in this case). Why not wait for someone to answer?

Comment: Ah ok sorry, now I know it!

Comment: @MarkJacon Do you have two accounts?

Comment: No I don't, mine is this one ;)

Answer (score 1):

The calculation is correct. It is a fact that $T$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ and not something you need to assume.

The situation often seen where one has to divide by $n-1$ to have an unbiased estimator for the variance is when the data is first used to estimate the unknown population mean. **However, that is not the case here.**

Here it is given that $U_i$ has mean zero. Namely, $U_i = \sigma Z_i$ where $Z_i$ are iid standard Normal such that each $Z_i^2$ is a Chi-square distribution with $1$ degree of freedom and $\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ is a Chi-sq\ with $n$ degree of freedom (instead of the reduced $n-1$).

The mean of a standard Chi-sq is $1$ as in $E[Z_i] = 1$. Therefore, $T = \frac1n \sum U_i^2$ has mean 
$$E[T] = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n\left( \sigma^2 E[Z_i^2] \right) = \frac1n \sigma^2 \sum_{i=1}^n 1 = \sigma^2$$